# longest common subsequence print all subsequences

Tags: algorithm, tree, lcs

how to display all the substrings of a longest common substring of two substring
i know the dp method to calculate length of lcs
but how to display all those lcs
code for lcs

```
       function LCSLength(X[1..m], Y[1..n])
C = array(0..m, 0..n)
for i := 0..m
   C[i,0] = 0
for j := 0..n
   C[0,j] = 0
for i := 1..m
    for j := 1..n
        if X[i] = Y[j]
            C[i,j] := C[i-1,j-1] + 1
        else
            C[i,j] := max(C[i,j-1], C[i-1,j])
return C[m,n]
```

i couldnt find a good article on net for how to find all lcs

string 1=abcabcaa
string 2=acbacba

all lcs

ababa
abaca
abcba
acaba
acaca
acbaa
acbca

i already know the dp method to calculate lcs
any help would be appreciated

i found this on wiki

```
             function backtrackAll(C[0..m,0..n], X[1..m], Y[1..n], i, j)
  if i = 0 or j = 0
    return {""}
    else if X[i] = Y[j]
    return {Z + X[i] for all Z in backtrackAll(C, X, Y, i-1, j-1)}
   else
    R := {}
    if C[i,j-1] ≥ C[i-1,j]
        R := backtrackAll(C, X, Y, i, j-1)
    if C[i-1,j] ≥ C[i,j-1]
        R := R ∪ backtrackAll(C, X, Y, i-1, j)
    return R
```

but am having diificulty in understanding it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Balgorithm%5D+longest+common+subsequence: 176 results

Answer (score 2):

A very intuitive way to do this is to store in additional 2D array backpointers, i.e.:

```
BP[i,j] := [(i-1,j-1)] if C[i,j] was created from C[i-1,j-1] (there was a match)
BP[i,j] := [(i,j-1), (i-1,j)] if C[i,j] could came from C[i,j-1] or C[i-1,j]
BP[i,j] := [(i,j-1)] if C[i,j] was created from C[i,j-1]
BP[i,j] := [(i-1,j)] if C[i,j] was created from C[i-1,j]
```

Now, let's define a directed graph. Any entry `[i,j]` in the array C corresponds to a vertex and backpointers correspond to edges.

There are `n*m` vertices and at most `2*n*m` edges, since one vertex has at most 2 backpointers.

Now the problem is to return all paths in this graph from the vertex `[n,m]` to the vertex `[0,0]`.

The graph is directed and there are no cycles, so you can simply follow the pointers by a DFS (without marking vertices as visited) and for each edge `([i,j] -> [i-1,j-1])` append the letter that corresponds to this match to a resulting string. The LCS is the string accumulated after reaching the `[0,0]` vertex.

Answer (score 0):

this is the simplest java program of LCS :-

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StrCmp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    String s1=s.nextLine();
    String s2=s.nextLine();
    String temp = "";
    char[] a = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] b= s2.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
        {
            if(s1.charAt(i)==s2.charAt(j))
            {   
                if(temp.contains(String.valueOf(s2.charAt(j)))){
                    break;
                }
                temp = temp + s2.charAt(j);
            }   
        }   
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Thank you for contributing an answer.  Please try to add some explanation/reasoning rather than just copy/paste code.

Answer (score -1):

Each c[i,j]  entry depends on only three other c table entries: c[i-1,j-1], c[i-1,j],
and c[i,j-1]. Given the value of c[i,j], we can determine in O(1) time which of
these three values was used to compute c[i,j]. Different values would be possible when there are more than one possible values for the previous 3 points, that is that they are same and highest at the same point. Then you would have to consider each of them.